# Does sleep get interrupted when any signal is received in perl?

Tags: linux, perl, signals, daemon

I have this simple perl daemon:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Daemon;

Proc::Daemon::Init;

my $continue = 1;

$SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = 0 };
$SIG{USR1} = sub { do_process(1) };

# basic daemon                                                                                    

boxesd_log("started boxesd");

while ($continue) {
    do_process(0);
    sleep(30);
}

boxesd_log("finished boxesd");

exit(0);

# required subroutines                                                                            

sub do_process {
    my ($notified) = @_;
    boxesd_log("doing it $notified");
}
```

But there is something that is not working right.

When the daemon starts, it logs every 30 seconds without the notification as expected:

```
Sat Oct 30 21:05:47 2010 doing it 0
Sat Oct 30 21:06:17 2010 doing it 0
Sat Oct 30 21:06:47 2010 doing it 0
```

The problem comes when I send the `USR1` signal to the process using `kill -USR1 xxxxx`.  The output is not what I expect:

```
Sat Oct 30 21:08:25 2010 doing it 1
Sat Oct 30 21:08:25 2010 doing it 0
```

I get two continuous entries, one from the signal handling subroutine and another form the ever running loop.  It seems as if the sleep gets interrupted whenever the `USR1` signal is received.

What is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sleep is getting interrupted in the sense that your program will handle the incoming signal, but the loop will continue (going back to sleep) until a TERM signal is received. This is documented behaviour for the [sleep()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) function:

> May be interrupted if the process receives a signal such as "SIGALRM".

Note that if you need to sleep for 30 seconds, even if interrupted by a signal, you can determine the number of seconds slept and then sleep again for the remainder:

```
while (1)
{
    my $actual = sleep(30);
    sleep(30 - $actual) if $actual < 30;
}
```

PS. You can read more about signal handling in [perldoc perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html), and in virtually any unix programming book by [W. Richard Stevens](http://www.kohala.com/start/). :)

Comment: You're not checking to see if your second `sleep` got interrupted too.  To handle it correctly, you need a loop of some sort, not just an `if`.

Comment: @mark4o: infinite until a signal interrupts it, yes, which is generally what daemons do.   (I removed the `$continue` variable for clarity, as it wasn't relevant to the core question of how `sleep` behaves in various conditions. Obviously one might want to make the actual code more complicated, e.g. sleeping again on a second interruption as cjm mentioned.)

Comment: Oh I thought that loop was supposed to replace the `sleep(30)`, not the whole main loop.  In that case I agree with cjm, and also the call to `do_process` is missing.

Comment: @mark: I'm sure you can pretend that the `do_process()` call is where it is supposed to be :p

Comment: $sleep = 30; while ($sleep > 0) $sleep -= sleep($sleep);